# Is there a lock() statement in Delphi Prism?

Tags: .net, delphi, oxygene

What is the equivalent of the c# lock() statement in Delphi Prism?  In VB.Net it's synclock() I believe.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://prismwiki.codegear.com/en/Locking_%28keyword%29

The locking keyword should be what you want